# Laravel 10 Logging - custom driver handle all logs

Tags: laravel, logging

Hi I have laravel 10 apps and now i would like to add some logging system:

My config file:

```
"channels" => [
        "stack" => [
            "driver" => "stack",
            "channels" => ["debug", "info", "warning", "critical"],
            "ignore_exceptions" => false,
        ],

        "debug" => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler::class,
            'with' => [
                'handler' => new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/debug.log'), 15),
                'minLevelOrList' => [Monolog\Level::fromName('DEBUG')],
            ],
        ],

        "info" => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            'via' => DatabaseLogger::class,
            'level' => 'info',
        ],

        "warning" => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler::class,
            'with' => [
                'handler' => new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/warning.log'), 15),
                'minLevelOrList' => [Monolog\Level::fromName('NOTICE'), Monolog\Level::fromName('WARNING')],
            ],
        ],

        "critical" => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler::class,
            'with' => [
                'handler' => new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path('logs/critical.log'), 15),
                'minLevelOrList' => [Monolog\Level::fromName('ERROR'), Monolog\Level::fromName('CRITICAL')],
            ],
        ],

//        "emergency" => [
//            'driver'  => 'monolog',
//            'handler' => Monolog\Handler\FilterHandler::class,
//            'with' => [
//                'handler' => new Monolog\Handler\TelegramBotHandler($apiKey = "<telegram_bot_api>", $channel = "@<channel_name>"),
//                'minLevelOrList' => [Monolog\Logger::ALERT, Monolog\Logger::EMERGENCY],
//            ],
//        ],
    ],
```

DatabaseLogger:

```
namespace App\Logs;

use Monolog\Logger;

class DatabaseLogger
{
    public function __invoke(array $config): Logger
    {
        return new Logger('info', [
            new DatabaseHandler(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
namespace App\Logs;

use JetBrains\PhpStorm\NoReturn;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;
use Monolog\LogRecord;

class DatabaseHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{

    #[NoReturn] protected function write(LogRecord $record): void
    {
        dump($record);
    }
}
```

and logs call

```
 $this->log::error("This is a debug message.");
 $this->log::debug("This is a debug message.");
 $this->log::info("This is a debug message.");
```

Result
[image]

I dont know why all logs debug, info and error are handling by Database logger instead only info . I know that i can filter it in handler but i would like to know how can i make it by config. Does configuration is ok ?